# Let's Encrypt の証明書データはオープンになっている？

Tags: letsencrypt

Let's Encrypt で取得した証明書の情報は、ウェブに対してオープンになっている、という話を伝聞で聞きました。

#### 質問

- Let's Encrypt で取得された証明書たちについての情報は、インターネットからどうにかして取得できるものなのでしょうか？

  - できる場合、それはどのようにしたら取得できますか？

Comment: この記事 [Let’s Encrypt の制限を分かりやすくまとめてみた【2019年版】](https://hackers-high.com/web-dev/lets-encrypt-limits/) の「証明書取得数の確認」に出ていた、このサイト [crt.sh](https://crt.sh/) の情報はどうでしょう？ **Let's Encryptが発行した証明書すべて** という纏め方は出来無さそうですが。